# Matching countries in data with python package pycountry

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to match countries from my data with the pythons inbuilt pycountry package. After running I am getting this error

```
raise AttributeError
```

AttributeError

```
countries_lookup = {}
countries = list(pycountry.countries)
for country in countries:    
    countries_lookup[country.alpha2]=country.name
country_names = list(countries_lookup.values())
country_names = [country.lower() for country in country_names]
country_names = set(country_names)
```

What should be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a typo to correct :

```
countries_lookup[country.alpha_2]=country.name
#-----------------------------^
```